# Get 403 For some reason PHP error i think

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

Okay so i recently decided to add a maintenance page to my site and it a .php file and so when i enable it to test it out i get a 403 error even with a different PC, Network.. i even tried VPN.. Can anyone explain why i get a 403 page when i enable it????

```
    <?php
session_id();
session_start();
ob_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$connection = mysql_pconnect("Hidden","Hidden","Hidden"); or die ("Error connecting to database.");
mysql_select_db("Hidden") or die ("Error connecting to database, hang tight, we are working on it.");
mysql_select_db("Hidden") or die ("Error connecting to database, hang tight, we are working on it.");


?>
<style>
body {
color:white;
font-family:Segoe UI;
}
body { background-image:url("http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/191/20288-gyrosigma-light-blue-background.jpg"); }
#Opacity {
background: url(Opacity.png);
padding:12px;
border:1px solid #969696;
border-radius:6px;
width:380px;
}

h3 {
color:#F5F5F5;
font-size:25px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

#h3sub {
color:#F5F5F5;
font-size:18px;
}

h2 {
color:#F5F5F5;
text-shadow:1px 0px 0px #999;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

input[type=text] {
width:300px;
background:white;
border:1px solid #999;
padding:4px;
font-family:Segoe UI;
border-radius:5px;
}

input[type=password] {
width:300px;
background:white;
border:1px solid #999;
padding:10px;
font-family:Segoe UI;
border-radius:7px;
}

#btn {
background:rgb(34,51,136);
padding:4px;
border-radius:7px;
color:white;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:30px;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34);
</style>
<center><td valign='top'>
            <center><img src='http://i.imgur.com/q1CODHB.png'></center>
        </td>
<div style='padding-bottom:0px;'></div>
<table>
        <h1><B><font color='darkred'>Maintenance Protocol</FONT></B></h1>
<h4><B><font color='darkred'>Gravitar is currently offline for maintenance and upgrades.</FONT></B></h4>
<h4><B><font color='darkred'>You will be redirected back to the website when this process is complete.</FONT></B></h4>
<br>
</br>
    <tr>

        <td valign='top'>
            <div id='Opacity'>
                        <h0><B><font color='darkblue'>Gravitar</FONT></B></h0>
                        <h2><font color='darkblue'>Developer Login</FONT></h2>
            <form action='' method='POST'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type='password' name='Password' placeholder='Passcode...'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='U'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='N'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='I'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='V'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='E'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='R'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='O'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='U'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='S'>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['Password'])));
$submit = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['submit'])));

    if ($submit) {

        $Passcode = "5y24G4H@$%Y56herGerefVVVVVVVerqcdfllllLOLFwew4wF!@#$";

        if ($Password == $Passcode) {

            $_SESSION['Admin']="hi";
            header("Location: index.php");

        }

    }
echo"<h4><center><font color='darkblue'>&copy Void Team Corporation. All Rights Reserved.</font></h4></center>";
?>
<?php
echo"</div></div>";
include "../Footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Wow! That totally fixed my code! OMG!!!

Comment: Hard to tell if you're being sarcastic.

Comment: it broke the whole site.

Comment: You will need to spend time converting it, the parameter constructs are different. In the current version of PHP mysql_* functions are completely removed, and the second you update PHP all those functions will become undefined. mysql_* is also broken in places, and may cause security problems.

Answer (score -1):

Use PDO Connection Request Commands As Mysql Connection Request Commands Are Depreted To use

And If You Even Get The Error 
Follow below steps

Check for URL errors and make sure you're specifying an actual web page file name and extension, not just a directory. Most websites are configured to disallow directory browsing so a 403 Forbidden message when trying to display a folder instead of a specific page is normal and expected.

NOTE: This is, by far, the most common reason for a website to return the 403 Forbidden error. Be sure you fully explore this possibility before investing time in the troubleshooting below.

Make Sure That You Have Used The Proper Include Url .

Make Sure That You Had Given The Proper CHOMD in Your HostManager Mostly You Should Give Read And Write Permissions .

And If you Have Done It But You Are Still Unable To Access It Then Make Sure If The File Is Under Any Sub Directory Make Sure That You Even Given Proper CHOMD Permissions To that Folder even .

Maximum The Possible Error was **Gaining Access **
So This Would Be Solved by following above steps .

As This Is An HTTP Error And you are using .php file so that even a problem could be at your htaccess file once pre check that you have any errors with it .

Even if you Didn't get the solution feel free to ping me .

Hope this both will sure help you to come out of error .